# connecting mlab database with pouchdb

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb, cloudant, mlab

I'm trying to build an application which sync between offline and online,its working with cloudant and pouchdb,i want to use mlab instead of cloudant
here is my code:

```
 this.db = new PouchDB('cloudo');

this.db = new PouchDB('cloudo');
 this.username = '';
    this.password = '';
    this.remote = 'https://oussemalaamiri.cloudant.com/museums/';
```

Comment: PouchDB uses the CouchDB sync protocol, so it will only work with databases that implement it, including CouchDB, Cloudant, and Couchbase. See https://pouchdb.com/guides/

Comment: And this: https://pouchdb.com/faq.html